# Flutter how to layout top to bottom of other layout

Tags: flutter

how to create text must top to bottom of image banner and don't overlap image?

If I'm use big screen it normal but not in small screen like this image

[image]

this is my flutter code

```
 return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: constraints.biggest.height,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          top: 0,
                          height: BannerHeight,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage("asset/images/banner.jpg"),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          )
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                            top: BannerHeight - BannerHeight / 4,
                            height: 100,
                            left: Left,
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("Nominal",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                Text("Rp. 1.000.000.000",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                Text("Point 10.538",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                              ]
                            )
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
```

what I need

[image: what I need]

Comment: what do you mean by **top of bottom other layer**?

Comment: like in xml have constraintlayout with attribute `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
 return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              /// you can use `BannerHeight` here
              height: BannerHeight,

              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    height: BannerHeight,
                    child: Image(
                      // image: AssetImage("asset/images/banner.jpg"),
                      image: AssetImage('assets/ocean.jpg'),
                      // fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 10,
                    // or percentages  BannerHeight * .25,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Nominal", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        Text("Rp. 1.000.000.000",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        Text("Point 10.538",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: why `SizedBox(height: BannerHeight,`? if sizedbox height same with bannerheight, So if I add other `positioned` bottom bannerimage, it's not show

Comment: I thought you wanted to text over banner, and while you've set banner height, we can use this height based. I'm not sure what are you trying to archive by adding another bottom banner image, to render in correct order, place last child to have priority over UI.  Widget render bottom to top on UI. can you update the Question of what are you doing, and an image that  you  are trying to archive?

Comment: I update my question, please see my pict what I need. sorry if my question is not clearly

Comment: The second row  is part of body, I mean outside that stack. Add row inside Column, if you face overflow issue, provide some height.

Comment: Try and let me know if you stuck some point.

Comment: ooh I Got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below answer hope its help to you:

```
  Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 150,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/wines.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
         
          Positioned(
            left: 12,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Nominal',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'RP 2312313123',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Point 10538',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Your Result Screen -> [image]

Comment: I try but text is not show. I replace my `stack` code with your code